# How to write unit test for my spring boot controller which uses a MongoRepository?

Tags: spring-boot, junit4, spring-data-mongodb

I managed to write a test for a basic controller which doesn't need any other services or APIs. But now I am struggling to apply this to a controller which interacts with a database.
I collected examples from different sources provided here on SO or on other sites google threw at me. Most of them are very old and are based on spring-boot 1.3 or 1.5 though I am using the latest 2.0.4.RELEASE

Some excerpts of what is working (I spare you the details as it is not relevant):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(HtmlController.class)
public class HtmlControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testIndex() {
        try {
            mockMvc.perform(get("/"));//etc.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail();
        }
    }
}
```

My more complex controller @Autorwires this interface:

```
public interface SetRepository extends MongoRepository<SetEntity, String>
```

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mongo-test) I found that I can just add `@DataMongoTest` to the test class and add a dependency for flapdoodle to my pom and it should work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

But I immediately get an `InitializationError` without any information about what is wrong. I found somewhere that I might need to add `spring.data.mongodb.port=0` to the `application.properties`, but this didn't change a thing.

What am I missing? Does anyone have an example test that also uses the MongoRepository interface?

Answer (score 0):

here you go with one example..

```
@DataMongoTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class MongoDbIntegrationTest {

 @Autowired
 private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate

    @Test
    public void test() {

   //Create your document object
        DBObject objectToSave = new DBObject();
        objectToSave.set /// set properties..
        mongoTemplate.save(objectToSave, "collection");

        // then assert result..
        assertThat(mongoTemplate.findAll(DBObject.class, "collection")).extracting("key")
            .containsOnly("value");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is using Junit5 and the MongoTemplate. SpringBoot currently still has Junit4 as the default, but I could give it a try with 5. But what about the Autowired MongoRepository within my controller which I want to test?

Comment: It seems, I can't combine `@WebMvcTest` and `@DataMongoTest` in one test. The former needs `@RunWith` which then has a conflicting bootsrapper

Comment: I am little confuse, you would like to write test cases for controller or repository, can you please post your complete pom with spring boot version and let me see, and also your test case you want to run..

Comment: I probably have to refactor my code a bit to have it easier with tests. My controllers are used for a REST API to CRUD on a database, but with some custom logic so I can't just let the spring magic take care of it. It doesn't make sense to just test the MongoRepository, I mean this is tested by spring, but I would like to test my custom logic. And it would be great to test the REST API with a database. An I am using 2.0.4.RELEASE.